# My code to delete a structure entry does not delete, and I cannot figure out why

Tags: c, struct, assert

I am currently trying to make a chess game. However, I found a bug where if I try to delete a piece (when it is killed) the program freezes and then quits.

The problem seems to be in the DeletePiece function. I was able to figure this out by moving printf's through my code until I could pinpoint where it's breaking. As soon as I try to free something, it freezes.

```
typedef struct {
        char *color;
        char *piece;
} PIECE;

PIECE *createPiece(char *color,char *piece) {

    PIECE *p=malloc(sizeof(PIECE));

    if(p==NULL) {
        printf("The memory allocation failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        p->color=malloc(2*sizeof(unsigned char));
        p->color=color;
        printf("piece is: %c \n",p->color[0]);
        p->piece=malloc(2*sizeof(unsigned char));
        p->piece=piece;
    }
}

PIECE *deletePiece(PIECE *p) {
    if(p!=NULL) {
        assert(p);
        assert(p->piece);
        assert(p->color);

        free(p->color);
        free(p->piece);
        p->color=NULL;
        p->piece=NULL;
        free(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `p != NULL` there is no point in asserting `p` afterwards...

Comment: And you just need **one** character for color and another for piece - they do not need to be strings.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings

Comment: The problems are in `CreatePiece()`.   `p->color` and `p->piece` are assigned using `malloc()` calls, then immediately reassigned.   If `p` is then passed to `DeletePiece()` the behaviour of `free(p->color)` and `free(p->piece)` are undefined.     Even worse, if `p` is not NULL, the function returns to the caller with no `return` statement, which causes ANYTHING the caller does to the value returned by `CreatePiece()` to have undefined behaviour.   If all of those problems are fixed, `DeletePiece()` will work okay, except for the fact that it also has a return type and falls off the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p->color=malloc(2*sizeof(unsigned char));
p->color=color;
```

This is not doing what you think it's doing. The first line allocates some space in memory and stores its address in `p->color`; the second line overwrites `p->color` with another address. The allocated memory is now lost since you lost its address.

You probably wanted to copy the contents of `color` into the space allocated to `p->color`, and you don't do that with an simple pointer assignment. Also, why allocate memory dynamically if you know how much you need everytime (`2*sizeof(unsigned char)`)? Just use arrays in your structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char color[2];
    char piece[2];
} PIECE;
```

Actually, the same thing could be said about dynamically allocating pieces. There are only 32 pieces in chess. No more, no less. Just use an array of pieces:

```
PIECE pieces[32];
```

Another point I don't get, but I can't really tell without seeing your full code, is that you use 2 characters for each color and piece. I'm relatively sure you only need one character, or better, one enumeration value, to store a color or a piece. Which eliminates the need for arrays in the first place.

Comment: The first point makes sense, but the pieces are dynamically allocated because when a piece dies, I'll delete it

Comment: @kunaldabomb You don't need to. Just put it aside. When you capture a piece in real life, you don't destroy it, you just place it next to the board. If you delete a piece whenever it gets captured, you will have to reallocate it if you want to restart (allow the player to play again), or even if you want to do some backtracking for AI moves (if you ever do that). It's totally unnecessary and doesn't offer any advantage in your code.